# pointer to function, struct as parameter

Tags: c, parameters, struct, type-conversion, function-pointers

Once again today with retyping..

In structure is pointer to function, in this function I want to be able work with data from this structure, so the pointer to structure is given as parameter.

Demo of this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tMYSTRUCTURE;

typedef struct{
    int myint;
    void (* pCallback)(struct tMYSTRUCTURE *mystructure);
}tMYSTRUCTURE;


void hello(struct tMYSTRUCTURE *mystructure){
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
}

int main(void) {
    tMYSTRUCTURE mystruct;
    mystruct.pCallback = hello;

    mystruct.pCallback(&mystruct);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

But I get Warning

> ..\src\retyping.c:31:5: warning: passing argument 1 of
>   'mystruct.pCallback' from incompatible pointer type
>   ..\src\retyping.c:31:5: note: expected 'struct tMYSTRUCTURE *' but
>   argument is of type 'struct tMYSTRUCTURE *'

expected 'struct tMYSTRUCTURE *' but is 'struct tMYSTRUCTURE *', funny!

any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: In your code, there's **no such thing as `struct tMYSTRUCTURE`**, it's an incomplete type.  All you have is an *anonymous* structure that also happens to be typedef'ed to `tMYSTRUCTURE`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612350#612350 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is being caused by `typedef`ing the structure and then using the `struct` keyword along with the `typedef`'d name. Forward declaring both the `struct` and the `typedef` fixes the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tagMYSTRUCTURE;
typedef struct tagMYSTRUCTURE tMYSTRUCTURE;

struct tagMYSTRUCTURE {
    int myint;
    void (* pCallback)(tMYSTRUCTURE *mystructure);
};


void hello(tMYSTRUCTURE *mystructure){
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
}

int main(void) {
    tMYSTRUCTURE mystruct;
    mystruct.pCallback = hello;

    mystruct.pCallback(&mystruct);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tMYSTRUCTURE_;

typedef struct tMYSTRUCTURE_ {
  int myint;
  void (* pCallback)(struct tMYSTRUCTURE_ *mystructure);
} tMYSTRUCTURE;


void hello(tMYSTRUCTURE *mystructure){
  puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
}

int main(void) {
  tMYSTRUCTURE mystruct;
  mystruct.pCallback = hello;

  mystruct.pCallback(&mystruct);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Note the difference between the `struct` name and the `typedef` name.  Yes, you can make them the same, but many people (myself included) find that confusing...  Common practice is to keep them distinct.

Admittedly, GCC's diagnostic here was more than a little bizarre.